# What's "at-username" called? at-handle?

Tags: social-media

I'm establishing standards for my code projects.

Among those, is that I want contributors attribute their notes to their GitHub username, in forms similar to: "@username".

I'll need to document this, but I'm not sure what it's called, maybe "at-handle" or something?

Comment: Just give the example you give there, don't use an obscure term people won't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) calls it "@username format" (since your unique textual identifier on the site is a "username"):

> The pattern is followed by one or more GitHub usernames or team names using the standard @username or @org/team-name format.

When used to [create a notification](https://github.blog/2011-03-23-mention-somebody-they-re-notified/) for another user, it's called an "@mention" but it doesn't sound like that applies to your situation.

Note of course that other sites may have their own terms for this type of thing.